# Connecting laptop to external LCD display

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution

So I have a Dell Inspiron 3501 and it supports full HD resolution (1920 x 1200 Pixels). I have connected my laptop to my Samsung LCD display (Model: SyncMaster B2230) via HDMI port.

However, when I go to "Display" option > Display Resolution, for some reason, I do not see all the resolutions for this external display. It only shows from 800 x 600 px UPTO 1280 x 1024 px

Any reason why all the resolutions are not shown (even though it is supported by both my laptop and external LCD display)

Also, any suggestions on what is the best way to setup this external display? I am seeing blurred text when using external display.

Comment: Does the laptop recognize the display as a Syncmaster B2230? Did you configure it as a separate (extended) desktop and not to mirror the primary desktop? Also: according to specs I’ve found online the Samsung Syncmaster B2230 only supports up to 1920x1080 (16:9) which is a different aspect ratio to your laptop screen.

Comment: Hey...thanks...So first thing, when you say, does it recognize my Syncmaster B2230, how exactly can I verify that? I mean I am able to view on this external display...Not sure if that means my laptop can recognize...Again, I am connecting via HDMI port and use HDMI to VGA converter, as my.Samsung SyncMaster B2230 display does not have an HDMI connector.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI cables have different types. I had some problem before.

Some are Ethernet enabled which is obsolete now. I don't know whether Ethernet has got to do with it. I did have some trouble before and I was troubleshooting by trying different HDMI cables. Apparently one may work while another may not.

Try with a new HDMI cable from the shop.

Otherwise use a DVI, VGA, or DisplayPort cable.

Comment: I wonder what does Ethernet have to do with that?

Comment: @gronostaj i have no idea but i did have some problem from my experience